# iOS9 Print Issue, preview changes after seconds and moves contents

Tags: ios, objective-c, printing, ios9

We have an app made with Xcode 6 and iOS8, we rebuilt it without changing anything for iOS9 and now when we try to print a document the preview appears and it changes the page format after some seconds. In the example below all sentences "jump" to the left. This also affects the printed page.

- It is probably a general iOS 9 problem, because it even happens when printing webpages with Safari.
- It is a problem for us if the text moves because we need to print to a fixed position, so a change of 1 cm is bad.
- We discovered that the jump happens after the printer sends available paper sizes (first call to the choosePaper-method happens with an empty array, second one with the actual paper sizes)

How to solve this problem? Is it possible to disable Print Preview?

Simple example:

```
- (IBAction)print:(id)sender
{
UIPrintInteractionController *controller = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

    if(!controller){
        NSLog(@"Couldn't get shared UIPrintInteractionController!");
        return;
    }

    UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler completionHandler =
    ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
    if(!completed && error){
            NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %ld", error.domain, (long)error.code);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"complete");
        }
    };

    UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    pic.delegate            = self;
    UIPrintInfo *printInfo  = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType    = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    printInfo.jobName       = @"My Job";
    printInfo.duplex        = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
    pic.printInfo           = printInfo;
    pic.showsPageRange      = YES;

    UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter *textPrint = [[UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter alloc] initWithMarkupText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><p><h1>Hello World</h1></p><p><h2>Hello World</h2></p><p><h3>Hello World</h3></p><p><h4>Hello World</h4></p><p><h5>Hello World</h5></p><p><h6>Hello World</h6></p></body></html>"]];

    pic.printFormatter = textPrint;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        [controller presentFromBarButtonItem:self.printButton animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
    }
    else {
        [controller presentAnimated:YES     completionHandler:completionHandler];
    }
}
```

Here are the two previews, the second one has moved from the desired position:
[image: Before second call to choosePaper]
[image: The second preview has moved the contents upwards and to the left]

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? I am having a similar issue with a label printer. If my user prints before the page loads, I get an 8.5x11" page scaled to a 2x3.5" label. If I wait for the printer to send its page size, it works properly.

Comment: We filed a bug with Apple, this was their response:
If you want something to be in an exact location, your code needs margin management.  What is happening here is that you are asked to draw the preview with generic margins.  And then after we get the exact margins from the printer, to re-draw with the printer specific margins.

Comment: Please see the 2014 WWDC video, or the Apple provided sample code, on how to control margins in the basic form.  In addition, you might want to consider a proper page render.  There you can perform a check to make sure that the printer physical limits are of the proper size to allow you to print with the margins you would like.  For example, many printers have a 0.56 bottom limit.  If you are setting the bottom inset to 0.50, you will get clipped.

Comment: We did not put any more effort in this, but I think they misunderstood the question. The weird thing for me is that having margins seems to scale the content, which does not make much sense...